# How to boot into Single-User recovery mode?

Tags: grub2, recovery-mode

In desktop Ubuntu there is handy GRUB menu, but there is no such menu in Ubuntu Server. How do I get into recovery (single-user) mode on Ubuntu Server then?

Answer (score 4):

I've found the answer - I had to hold shift to see the GRUB menu.

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode