# ubuntu 14.04 crashing and restarting

Tags: 14.04

After the latest update (10.03.2015 at abt 07 hrs am Finnish time) using Software Updater my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS started to close and restart when starting whatever program. In the beginning it took 5 - 10 min before this happened. Now it happens almost immediately. If I don't do anything it stays alive. I can't even check the crash reports. Please, I need urgent help!

Comment: This may also happen due to failing hard disk. Try booting through a live cd and check the hard disk SMART stats.

Comment: Thanks. The hard disk is ok. I have already got most of the systems running. I'm still working with my apache2 configurations. And one navigation sw (qtVml) is not working. Maybe I have to reinstall it. However, a number of Ubuntu error messages has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a LiveCD to read the log files in your computer?  Or did you try to start your computer in single-user mode as mentioned below:

- [How to boot into Single-User recovery mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32623/how-to-boot-into-single-user-recovery-mode)
- http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/recover-your-system-with-single-user-mode-in-ubuntu-ubuntu-11-10.html#axzz3TxtnKpGK

If we do not have sufficient information, it is difficult to tell.

Comment: Hi. I restarted the machine in Ubuntu recovery mode and did there the dbkg configuration. After that I started the machine a couple times until it finally succeeded. Now at least nautilus is running so I can try to find the reason(s) for crashing. Any advise where to start?